# Why does my launch.json file get an error on this line: "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\serve"

Tags: angular, launcher, vscode-debugger

When I try to launch the debugger for an Angular application, I get this error: 
"Attribute 'program' does not exist ('C:\repos\recipes\serve')

I've tried deleting the existing launch.json file in the .vscode folder and generating a new one.  The same one is generated when I select "Add Configuration" under the Debug dropdown menu.

I am using "ng serve" to run the app in localhost:4200

My launch.json file looks like this:

```
{    "version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\serve",
        "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/dist/out-tsc/**/*.js"
        ]
    }
]}
```

I expect the debugger to run and hit a breakpoint in my Angular TypeScript code but I get this error:

"Attribute 'program' does not exist ('C:\repos\recipes\serve')'

Comment: Try only one backslash, not two.  And if that doesn't fix it, try one forward slash.  Those slashes do not need to be escaped.

Comment: Tried one backslash then one forward slash.  Neither works.  Code is generating this file with 2 backslashes.  Does it have anything to do with running it with "ng serve" in the terminal window?

Answer (score 0):

Insert in `{}`

`{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\serve",
        "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/dist/out-tsc/**/*.js"
        ]
    }
]
}`

Comment: VSCode generates the file between {} - I just left off the first brace in my code sample above (I'll correct it. - thanks)